# (Java) Is it possible to have a function return an operator?

Tags: java, operators

I want to know if it's possible to return an operator as if it were an object or a type.

This would be for parsing through a 2D array of coordinates to determine the bounding box of where two polygons overlap. The function's output would determine the boolean statement of the for-loops so the algorithm can start its parsing from the back of the polygon based on the direction of the polygon's motion.

```java
public <operator> function(int value){
    if(value < 0) {
        return >=;
    }
    return <=;
}
```

The syntax above is obviously completely wrong but I was optimally looking for something similar.

I would want to use the function similarly to this:

```java
if(var1 function(value) var2)
```

Does anything like this even exist? If not, is there any other way to switch between >= and <=?

Comment: Something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a [`BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html):

```
public BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> function(int value) {
    if(value < 0) {
        return (a, b) -> a >= b;
    }
    return (a, b) -> a <= b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, you cannot return an operator. According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) in regard to:

`return Expression`<sub>`opt`</sub>`;`

> The Expression must denote a variable or value of some type T, or a compile-time error occurs.

Since an operator is not a variable or value, you cannot return it.

Why not just have the method do the comparison:

```
public boolean function(int value, int num1, int num2){
    if(value < 0) {
        return num1 >= num2;
    }
    return num1 <= num2;
}
```

And then call it as:

```
if(function(value, var1, var2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functional interfaces of Java 8.

Since you want 2 operands, and a boolean result, you could simply use [`BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html), but since you want the 2 operands to be of the same type, that would require you to repeat the type, so you could create a new functional interface, e.g. named `BinaryPredicate`:

```
interface BinaryPredicate<T> extends BiPredicate<T, T> {
    // nothing to add
}
```

Then your method could be, e.g. like this, if you wanted the operands to be a type that implements `Comparable`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> BinaryPredicate<T> objectOperator(int value){
    if (value < 0)
        return (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b) >= 0;
    return (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b) <= 0;
}
```

If you wanted the operands to be `int` values, you could create this instead:

```
interface IntBinaryPredicate {
    boolean test(int a, int b);
}
```

Then do your method like this:

```
public static IntBinaryPredicate intOperator(int value){
    if (value < 0)
        return (a, b) -> a >= b;
    return (a, b) -> a <= b;
}
```

Here is how you would use them:

```
BinaryPredicate<String> stringOp = objectOperator(1);
if (stringOp.test("Foo", "Bar"))
```

```
IntBinaryPredicate intOp = intOperator(1);
if (intOp.test(13, 42))
```